# How can I show the month for a Enterprise Custom Date Field in the Project Center for Grouping?

Tags: ms-project, project-management-style, ms-project-2013, enterprise

I setup a Enterprise Custom Field for a Key Date that leadership wants to group by year and month. I thought I could just make 2 new Enterprise Custom Fields, one to parse out the Month and the other to parse out the year from another Enterprise Custom Field that is defined as a Project level date field that users pick from the calendar. I've tried several approaches using the following formulas and only get blanks in the target fields.

Field 1 = 2/2/2025 
Field 1 Month = Month(Field 1) returns blank;
Field 1 Month = Mid(Field 1, 3, 2) returns blank;
Field 1 DateSerial(Field 1) returns blank;

I noted that in the Formula edit box that the Enterprise Custom Fields are not listed as available fields and am now wondering if the available fields are limited to system fields and no calculations can be performed on Enterprise Custom Fields. So, how can the month and year be parsed out of an Enterprise Custom date field? If I can get the month to work, the year should work the same by using "Year(Field 2)" but, I get nothing. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From [Add or edit enterprise custom fields in Project Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/project/add-or-edit-enterprise-custom-fields-in-project-server):

To add a field to the formula, click Pick field, point to a field type, and then click the name of the field that you want to reference. **To reference an existing Enterprise Custom Field**, point to a field type, point again to a custom field type (such as Custom Date or Custom Finish), and then click the Enterprise Custom Field that you want.